# Micronaut - not possible to use PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, micronaut

I'am new to micronaut and I try to follow this little [project](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html). However I would like it to work with postgres.

My `application.yml` looks like this:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: hello-world
  datasources:
    default:
      url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
      username: test
      password: test
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    default:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          hbm2ddl:
            auto: update
          show_sql: true
```

I have access to the database via `intellij`.
In the `pom.xml` I have the following dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Additionally it is mentioned in the link that one needs `annotionProcessor`, so I added this to my build profile:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

So now everytime I try to do the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
```

However I already have `annotation processing` enabled. And I also have a `@Entity`-class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String userName;


    public User() {
    }


    public User(@NotBlank final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

What exactly am I missing in my setup?

Comment: "not possible to use PersistenceContext" - That is incorrect.

Comment: What would you suggest? I used this formulation because I could not inject the entity manager but it was possible to inject other beans

Comment: When you said "not possible to use PersistenceContext" are you really asking how to get a reference to the `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues with my setup.

1. `datasource` and `jpa` need to be at root level
2. The `@Entity` needs a `@Id`

So in the end the `application.yml` looks like this:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: hello-world
datasources:
  default:
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
    username: test
    password: test
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
jpa:
  default:
    packages-to-scan:
      - 'test'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
```

And the `@Entity`-Class needs an `@Id`-Attribute:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;


    public User() {
    }


    public User(@NotBlank final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }


    public void setUserName(final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```